# "The expression is not valid" when performing SharePoint Rest call

Tags: rest, sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint site and when I call

```
    SITE/_api/web/lists/
```

it gives me the data for all the lists no problem. The problem is once I start querying for a specific list (for example one called "Environments") by calling

```
    SITE/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("Environments")/
```

it gives me the error

```
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryExceptionThe expression "web/lists/getbytitle(Environments)/items" is not valid.
```

Am I not building the URL right or is there something wrong with the site.

Comment: Getting: "The expression \"web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/Ikeda Sensei's New Year's Message - 2020.pdf')/$value\" is not valid." when calling get file by server relative url API. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use apostrophes (`'`) instead of quotation marks around the title of your list.

If your list tile has apostrophes in its title, you need to escape those by replacing each apostrophe with `%27%27`.

Comment: Getting: "The expression \"web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/Ikeda Sensei's New Year's Message - 2020.pdf')/$value\" is not valid." when calling get file by server relative url API. Any idea?

Comment: @MayureshSrivastava You've got two apostrophes in the filename that you'll need to escape by replacing them with "%27%27". The two apostrophes are in "Sensei's" and in "Year's".

Comment: I am encoding the entire url which is returning: "https://<host>/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared%20Documents/Ikeda%20Sensei's%20New%20Year's%20Message%20-%202020.pdf')/$value" and still getting same error. If I do as you suggested , https://<host>/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Shared%20Documents/Ikeda%20Sensei%27s%20New%20Year%27s%20Message%20-%202020.pdf')/$value, still same error. I tried converting - to %2D but still same. Can you suggest?

Comment: Try replacing each apostrophe with two `%27%27` encodings, not just one `%27`. So `https://<host>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/Ikeda Sensei%27%27s New Year%27%27s Message - 2020.pdf')/$value`

Comment: It seems to be working but why two '%27%27` and I am not sure how this thing can be handled as I am using built-in encode method to encode and that is not encoding apostrophe as it is a valid character in a URL and obviously I can not and should not encode manually for a particular file.

Comment: The need to use double apostrophes instead of single apostrophes is probably because the REST API is already using single apostrophes to detect the beginning and end of the filename when using `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl`. It sounds like there are other special characters that can also cause problems in filenames, like the `$` sign, so it may be worth having your own method for checking filenames and replacing special apostrophes before plugging them into the REST call. See the answer here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/264381/38950

Answer (score 2):

Correct REST URL to get list items is :

```
http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items
```

You are missing single quotes around List name.

Check MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx

Comment: Getting: "The expression \"web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/Ikeda Sensei's New Year's Message - 2020.pdf')/$value\" is not valid." when calling get file by server relative url API. Any idea?